# Send Button For Chat Client isn't working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get a chat system implemented I am not exactly sure what the problem is which is why I have brought my code here for review. I suspect that there may be an issue with my javascript code.
Update: 1:21 AM EST 01/19/2023
I changed the ID to send but the button is still not functioning.
It is not transmitting messages.
There is no data being sent to the messages table in the database called market
Here are some pics of the database and the chatbox
https://ibb.co/8DVLBfN
https://ibb.co/WWcx5xC

I also created a realTimeChat page the code is below.

realTimeChat.php

```
    <?
    include("DBConnection.php");
    $FromUser = $_POST["FromUser"];
    $ToUser = $_POST["ToUser"];
    $output="";
    $chats = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM messages where (FromUser = `".$FromUser."` AND ToUser = `".$Touser."`) 
    OR (FromUser = `".$ToUser."` AND Touser = `".$FromUser."`) ") or die ("Failed to query database".mysqli_error());
    while($chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chats))
    {
        if($chat["FromUser"] == $_SESSION["userID"])
        $output .= "<div style=`text-align:right;`>
        <p style=`background-color:lightblue: word-wrap:break-wordl display:inline-block; padding:5px; border-radius:10px; max width:70%;`>
        ".$chat["Message"]."
        </p>
        </div>";
        else $output.="<div style=`text-align:left;`>
        <p style=`background-color:yellow; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block; padding:5px border-radius:10px;
        max width: 70%;`>
        ".$chat["Message"]."
        </p>
        </div";
    }
    
    echo $output;
    
    
    ?>
```

chat-index-page.php

```
`<?php
session_start();
include("DBConnection.php");
include("links.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "market");
if(isset($_GET["userId"]))
{
    $_SESSION["userId"] = $_GET["userId"];
    header("location: chatbox.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="
    
    border: none;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    
    ">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Please Select Your Account</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                <ol></ol>
                <?php
                $users = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users") or die ("Failed to query database".mysqli_error($mysql));
                while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users))
                {
                    echo '<li style="list-style:none;"><a href="chat-index-page.php?userId='.$user["Id"].'">'.$user["User"].'</a></li> ';
                }
                
                ?>
                </ol>
                <a href="registerUser.php" style="float:right;">Register here.</a>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

chatbox.php

```
<?php

`session_start();
include("DBConnection.php");
include("links.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "market");
$users = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = '" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "'")
    or die("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($mysql));

while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $_SESSION["Id"] = $user["Id"];
    $_SESSION["User"] = $user["User"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="password-strength-indicator.css">
    <title>Messages</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION["User"]; ?></p>
               
                <p>Send message to:</p>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <?php
                    $msgs = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users")
                        or die("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($mysql));
                    while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgs)) {
                        echo '<li><a href="?ToUser=' . $msg["Id"] . '">' . $msg["User"] . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
                <a href="chat-index-page.php"><-- Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4><?php
                                if (isset($_GET["toUser"])) {
                                    $userName = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users Id = '" . $_GET["toUser"] . "' ")
                                        or die("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($connect));
                                    $uName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userName);
                                    echo '<input type="text" value=' . $_GET["toUser"] . ' id="toUser" hidden />';
                                    echo $uName["User"];
                                } else {
                                    $userName = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users")
                                        or die("Failed to query database" . mysqli_error($connect));
                                    $uName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userName);
                                    $_SESSION["toUser"] = $uName["Id"];
                                    echo '<input type="text" value=' . $_SESSION["toUser"] . ' id="toUser" hidden />';
                                    echo $uName["User"];
                                }
                                ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="msgBody" style="height:400px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_GET["toUser"])) {
                                $chats = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM messages where (FromUser = '".$_SESSION["userId"]."' AND
                                 ToUser = '".$_GET["toUser"]."') OR (FromUser = '".$_GET["userId"]."' AND
                                 ToUser = '".$_SESSION["userId"]."')")
                                or die("Failed to query database". mysqli_error($connect));
                                $chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chats);
                            }
                            else {
                                $chats = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM messages where (FromUser = '".$_SESSION["userId"]."' AND
                                ToUser = '".$_SESSION["toUser"]."') OR (FromUser = '".$_SESSION["userId"]."' AND
                                ToUser = '".$_SESSION["userId"]."')")
                               or die("Failed to query database". mysqli_error($connect));


                               while($chat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chats)) {
                                 if($chat["FromUser"] == $_SESSION["userId"]) {
                                    echo "
                                    <div style='text-align:right;'>
                                        <p style='background-color: lightblue; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;
                                        padding:5px; border-radius:10px; max width: 70%;'>
                                        ".$chat["Message"]."
                                        </p>
                                    </div>";
                                 } else {
                                    echo "
                                    <div style='text-align:left;'>
                                        <p style='background-color: yellow; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;
                                    padding:5px; border-radius:10px; max-width: 70%;'>
                                    ".$chat["Message"]."
                                    </p>
                                    </div>";
                                 }

                               };
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer"style="position:absolute">
                            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" style="
                            height: 250px;
                            width: 500px;
                            position: absolute;
                            margin-top: -390px;
                            margin-left: -110px;"></textarea>
                            <button id="reg_btn" class="btn btn-primary" style="
                            position: absolute;
                            width: 100px;
                            top: -140px;
                            left: 286px;">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#send").on("click",function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"insertMessage.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    FromUser: $("#FromUser").val(),
                    ToUser: $("#ToUser").val(),
                    message: $("#message").val()
                },
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("#message").val("");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

insertMessage.php

```
`<?php
session_start();
include("DBConnection.php");
$FromUser = $_POST["FromUser"];
$ToUser = $_POST["ToUser"];
$Message = $_POST["Message"];
$output="";
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (FromUser, ToUser, Message) VALUES ('$FromUser','$ToUser', '$message')";
if($connect -> query($sql))
{
    $output.="";
}
else 
{
    $output.="Error. Please Try Again.";
}
echo $output;
?>`
```

I have tried reviewing the code to see if there were any syntax errors but there doesn't appear to be any.
When clicking the send button nothing happens when it should be sending messages. The send button for some reason is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Send button element id is "reg-btn" in <chatbox.php>, but you are adding a listener to element with id "send".

Change button id to "send".

Comment: I changed the ID to "send" it seemed like it was working but it wasn't sending data to the proper table within the database. Here are some pictures of what the chatbox looks like and what the database looks like https://ibb.co/8DVLBfN
https://ibb.co/WWcx5xC there should be data that is inserted into the messages table but nothing is being sent.